# How to get string starting after particular character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `ABC` which has a column `xyx` that contains values like `(888) 477-8977x110` or `(888) 477-8977 ext 110`.

How do I get values after `x` or `ext` in SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

Perhahaps a little overkill

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Phone] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('(888) 477-8977x110')
,('(888) 477-8977 ext 110')
,('(888) 477-8977 extention 110')
,('(888) 477-8977 e 110')
,('888.477.8977ext110')
,('(888) 477-8977')


Select * 
      ,Ext = ltrim(NullIf(reverse(ltrim(left(reverse(Phone),patindex('%[a-z]%',reverse(Phone)+'a')-1))),Phone))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Phone                           Ext
(888) 477-8977x110              110
(888) 477-8977 ext 110          110
(888) 477-8977 extention 110    110
(888) 477-8977 e 110            110
888.477.8977ext110              110
(888) 477-8977                  NULL
```

Comment: I like this *overkill*, it is called *defensive* :-D

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT REPLACE(column,'(888)','') FROM ABC;
```

Or use SUBSTRING

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column,6,15) FROM ABC;
```

Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql

Comment: You can certainly use SUBSTRING to accomplish this, but the code you have in your answer does not return the values after x or ext.

Answer (score 0):

Use Charindex and Substring.

```
            DECLARE @word VARCHAR(254) = '(888) 477-8977 ext 110'
            SELECT  IIF(CHARINDEX('ext', @word) > 0, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@word, 0,
                                                                          LEN(@word)
                                                                          - LEN(SUBSTRING(@word,
                                                                          CHARINDEX('ext',
                                                                          @word),
                                                                          LEN(@word)))))), LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@word,
                                                                          0,
                                                                          LEN(@word)
                                                                          - LEN(SUBSTRING(@word,
                                                                          CHARINDEX('x',
                                                                          @word),
                                                                          LEN(@word)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing more then `x` or `ext` you could take this road:

```
DECLARE @tblPhoneNumber TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, PhoneNumber VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblPhoneNumber VALUES
 ('(888) 477-8977x110')
,('(888) 477-8977 ext 110');

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(
       CAST(
         '<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'ext','x'),'x','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML
           ).value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)')
       ))
FROM @tblPhoneNumber;
```

First all `ext` will be `x` , then all `x` will work as XML elements.
The `.value()` picks the second element, which is the needed one.